# CIS Hardening 1.1.6 Ensure separate partition exists for /var

Tags: ansible, molecule

I've been working on automating the CIS benchmark guidelines on CentOS8 using Ansible, Molecule on Vagrant. I've been referencing the ansible scripts of repos such as https://github.com/MindPointGroup/RHEL7-CIS and is facing problem on point "1.1.6 Ensure separate partition exists for /var".

Running commands such as `shell: mount | grep "on /var "` does not seem to create a separate partition for /var and running `mount | grep -E '/var'` returns `sunrpc on /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs`rather than the expected `/dev/xvdg1 on /var type xfs (rw,relatime,data=ordered)`

I've tried using `parted` on ansible to automated the creation of a partition for /var but always get a error message that the partition is too small.

What can I do to ensure /var is on a separate partition?

Comment: Are you aware of the `ansible_mounts` hostvar, which contains a `mount` key in them?

Comment: I'm not familiar with ansible_mounts. Searching about it only shows me documentation on variables. Do you mind explaining or know of any documentation or tutorial on using of ansible_mounts?

Comment: @bryan the following command should get you started to explore your localhost mounts as an example => `ansible localhost -m setup -a filter=ansible_mounts`

Answer (score 1):

To catch the correct path, run:

> mount | grep -E "(^| )/var( |$)"

or

> mount | grep -E "(^|\s)/var(\s|$)"

Answer (score 1):

There's two steps to compliance, and they're repeated iteratively.  First you apply the hardening configuration.  Then review/scan.  Repeat until there are no findings.

Configuration phase:
To ensure that `/var` is mounted on a separate partition, you need to move the original `/var` to another folder (e.g. `/var_old`) build a new partition, mount it at `/var`, and move the contents from `/var_old` to `/var`.  Best to do this with the system booted to a live CD.  Actually, it's best to build the system that way from the start.

Review/scanning phase:
Similar to what was suggested in the other answers:

```
mount | grep -E "(\s)/var(\s)"
```

Should do the job.  The key difference is the regex expression '"(\s)/var(\s)"`.

This means `/var` with a whitespace before and after.  With the `mount` command, this is a space.

You could also use that same expression against /etc/fstab. `grep -E "(\s)/var(\s)" /etc/fstab`

Grepping against `mount` doesn't tell you if the mount is persistent or temporary.  Grepping against `/etc/fstab` doesn't tell you if the mount is working and active.  If you're doing this for compliance, make sure you use the test suggested in the CIS guidelines.

So your question appears to be how to test for compliance, but if you really want to know how to comply, I've listed that too.

You could also write an ansible playbook to do the configuration part, but trying to move /var while the system is live would be extremely intricate and not worth the hassle...unless you need to do this for hundreds of systems.  In which case my suggestion would be to write the playbooks necessary to reinstall all the systems, and have /var, and /var/log/audit, and /tmp, and /home all on separate partitions.  Once you've done that, congratulations, you've established Infrastructure as Code in your organization.  The alternative is automating the process I laid out above.  Doable, but you're going to have to manually boot to a live CD or network image or at least recovery mode.